# Powershell for SharePointOnline : Grant special right

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a question :
I have a sharepoint online with 59 folders (in shared folder) with inside each a sub an sud folder (158 totals folders).
I have 59 AD SecurityGroup and i would like to put the good folder owner at each folder.
I have a cvs with in
column A : the folder's name into shared folder
Column B : the security group

Last request and not the easiest : on each 59 folder i would like to put "reader right" and at last sub-folder founded on each subfolder : "contributor right".

Did someone can help me please ?

[image: Folder and subfolder sample]

trying something like :

```
$SiteURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/testsharepoint"
$ListName="Documents"
$ParentFolderURL = "/Documents partages" #Site Relative Path of the document Library
$UserAccount = "test.fr"
$GroupName = "mygroupname" # Nom du groupe de sécurité Azure AD
$readRight = "Lecture"
$EditRight = "Modification"

#Get all Folders from the given location - Exclude Hidden
$AllFolders= Get-PnPFolderItem -ItemType Folder -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $ParentFolderURL | Where {($_.Name -ne "Forms") -and (-Not($_.Name.StartsWith("_")))}
$AllFolders


#Iterate through each Folder
ForEach($Folder in $AllFolders)
{
    Write-host ("Granted Permission to '{0}' at {1} " -f $Folder.Name,$Folder.ServerRelativeUrl)
    #Grant Contribute permissions to the Folder
    
 Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $ListName -Identity $Folder.ListItemAllFields -User $UserAccount -AddRole $EditRight
}
```

that's not ok for group but for specific user and only for the 1 folder lvl
please help ;)